@Trasactional annotation not working with webflux 3.3.2
We have recently started upgrading spring webflux version 2.7X to 3.3.2. After this upgrade, when we hit API with Postman it goes to controller layer and if service layer method is annotated with @Transactional, it does not reach to service layer. Further we got Error: socket hang up
But none of this found to be working. We found this question as well from where only we tried #1. Please suggest what could be wrong here.
We tried to debug by enabling org.springframework.transaction level to DEBUG but no luck
Further, to solve the issue, we have tried:

JTA @Transactional from "jakarta.transaction.Transactional" [latest version 2.0.1]
transactionalOperator from "org.springframework.transaction.reactive.TransactionalOperator"
Creating bean of transactionManager from "org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.R2dbcTransactionManager".


Maybe helps: Reactive Transactions with Spring. Reactive stack limits you and you don't have the use case for it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Can you please post controller and service classes code, so that is shown how the service is annotated and injected into the controller? I tried to reproduce your issue but transactions were opened and closed correctly. Anyway, try also to set  org.springframework.transaction level to TRACE, because DEBUG may be not enough.

We have two dependencies in our POM file.
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.12.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

then We removed "io.r2dbc" dependency and it worked. But could not understand why it was working before upgrading version.
